# How to resolve "Register/latch pins with no clock driven by root clock pin" error in Vivado?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado, register-transfer-level

As a learning exercise I am doing some HDMI experiments on an FPGA using VHDL. When coming to implement it in Vivado (2017.1) I am encountering the following warning in the timing report:

```
There are 11 register/latch pins with no clock driven by root clock pin: Hsync_i_reg/Q (HIGH)
```

I have opened the implemented schematic and looked for the pin in question. It seems to be connected to the same clock that everything else is connected to (and those are not flagged in the timing report), so I am confused as to what the errors above are referring to. Here are some shots from the schematics:

[image]
[image]

Here is the VHDL code of the offending design:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ctrl_gen is
    generic (
        ha: integer := 96; --hpulse
        hb: integer := 144; --hpulse+hbp
        hc: integer := 784; --hpulse+hbp+hactive
        hd: integer := 800; --hpulse+hbp+hactive+hfp
        va: integer := 2; --vpulse
        vb: integer := 35; --vpulse+vbp
        vc: integer := 515; --vpulse+vbp+vactive
        vd: integer := 525 --vpulse+vbp+vactive+vfp
    );
    port (
        clk25: in std_logic; --tmds clock (25mhz)
        hsync: out std_logic; --horizontal sync
        vsync: out std_logic; --vertical sync
        hactive: out std_logic; --active portion of hsync
        vactive: out std_logic; --active portion of vsync
        dena: out std_logic --display enable
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of ctrl_gen is
    signal hsync_i, hactive_i, vactive_i, vsync_i : std_logic;
begin
    -- horizontal signals generation
    hproc : process (clk25)
        variable hcount: integer range 0 to hd := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk25) then
            hcount := hcount + 1;

            if (hcount=ha) then
                hsync_i <= '1';
            elsif (hcount=hb) then
                hactive_i <= '1';
            elsif (hcount=hc) then
                hactive_i <= '0';
            elsif (hcount=hd) then
                hsync_i <= '0';
                hcount := 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- vertical signals generation
    vproc : process (hsync_i)
        variable vcount: integer range 0 to vd := 0;
    begin
        if falling_edge(hsync_i) then
            vcount := vcount + 1;

            if (vcount=va) then
                vsync_i <= '1';
            elsif (vcount=vb) then
                vactive_i <= '1';
            elsif (vcount=vc) then
                vactive_i <= '0';
            elsif (vcount=vd) then
                vsync_i <= '0';
                vcount    := 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    dena <= hactive_i and vactive_i;
    hsync <= hsync_i;
    vactive <= vactive_i;
    hactive <= hactive_i;
end behavioral;
```

On reflection, I think that the warning is telling me that Hsync_i_reg/Q is the clock used for the Vcount registers, not that Hsync_i_reg itself if not connected to the root clock pin?

Is the method I have used bad practice and unlikely to work? The overall design is not working and I'm trying to understand whether this is the cause.

Thanks.

Comment: Was that constraint correctly applied? See the report after the xdc was opened and read into the design. Sometimes rules get not applied.

Comment: @Paebbels Sorry, could you elaborate on where I could find this out? When I change the clock period in the constraint, it affects the WNS in the timing report, so it is definitely being applied somehow. But correctly applied, I am not so sure?

Comment: Not possible to reproduce this without a [mcve]. Maybe my magic ball will help. No, sorry. Please add more info and some code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The code for the `FCU` entity might be of particular interest.

Comment: @JHBonarius I have modified my question to provide a more concrete example which should meet the MCVE requirements. The example is slightly different, but the errors I'm experiencing are the same.

Comment: I've run your code (vivado 2017.3) bare with a constraints file containing only `create_clock -name clk25 -period 40.000 [get_ports clk25]` and I had no errors whatsoever... So the example is not reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see potential design issues. First being the use of `variable` for objects that are actually clocked signals. Secondly, you're using a generated signal as a clock input. That's also not nice.

I would modify your code to the following (not tested if it completely does what your code did before)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ctrl_gen is
    generic (
        ha: integer := 96; --hpulse
        hb: integer := 144; --hpulse+hbp
        hc: integer := 784; --hpulse+hbp+hactive
        hd: integer := 800; --hpulse+hbp+hactive+hfp
        va: integer := 2; --vpulse
        vb: integer := 35; --vpulse+vbp
        vc: integer := 515; --vpulse+vbp+vactive
        vd: integer := 525 --vpulse+vbp+vactive+vfp
    );
    port (
        clk25: in std_logic; --tmds clock (25mhz)
        hsync: out std_logic; --horizontal sync
        vsync: out std_logic; --vertical sync
        hactive: out std_logic; --active portion of hsync
        vactive: out std_logic; --active portion of vsync
        dena: out std_logic --display enable
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of ctrl_gen is
    signal hsync_i, hactive_i, vactive_i, vsync_i : std_logic;

    signal hcount: integer range 0 to hd-1 := 0;
    signal vcount: integer range 0 to vd-1 := 0;
begin
    -- horizontal signals generation
    hproc : process (clk25)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk25) then
            if hcount < hd-1 then
                hcount <= hcount + 1;
            else
                hcount <= 0;
            end if;

            if (hcount=ha-1) then
                hsync <= '1';
            end if;
            if (hcount=hb-1) then
                hactive_i <= '1';
            end if;
            if (hcount=hc-1) then
                hactive_i <= '0';
            end if;
            if (hcount=hd-1) then
                hsync <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- vertical signals generation
    vproc : process (clk25)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk25) then
            if hcount = hd-1 then -- moment of falling_edge hsync.
                if vcount < vd-1 then
                    vcount <= vcount + 1;
                else
                    vcount <= 0;
                end if;

                if (vcount=va-1) then
                    vsync <= '1';
                end if;
                if (vcount=vb-1) then
                    vactive_i <= '1';
                end if;
                if (vcount=vc-1) then
                    vactive_i <= '0';
                end if;
                if (vcount=vd-1) then
                    vsync <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    dena <= hactive_i and vactive_i;
    vactive <= vactive_i;
    hactive <= hactive_i;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think:

```
signal hcount: integer range 0 to hd-1 := 0;
signal vcount: integer range 0 to vd-1 := 0;
```

Is not a valid synthesis type for `hcount`, `vcount`: it should be `std_logic_vector`

Comment: That's not true!